# ODI 12c integration knowledge module merge when using reusable mapping

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

Is there away to use the  integration knowledge model Merge when using reusable mapping?
I am able to use the Merge IKM when just using datastores but when I added a reusable mapping the option no longer appears on the IKM drop down.

Answer (score 0):

On the logical tab of your mapping, click on the target datastore. Under the *Target* tab in the properties pane, change the **Integration Type** and set it to *Incremental Update* or *None*. Then go back in the Physical design and the Merge IKMs should be available in the drop-down.

[image]

The Integration Type is a pre-filter for the loading strategies. I personally prefer to set it to *None* so it doesn't filter out any KM and I can have two different Physical design for the same mapping :

- the initial load with an Insert Append IKM and truncate set to true.
- the incremental load with a Merge IKM